# How to get user's own mobile number from windows phone 7 or 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8.1

I want to extract "user **own** mobile number", not his whole phone book. i am using c# as the developing language. thank you

Comment: I have tried accessing the whole phone book but the users contact was not available .

Comment: What do you mean by extracting mobile number - from plain text, phone book, specific user? Can you give us an example?

Comment: @MartinSuchan to me at least it is pretty obvious it's the phone number of the device he wants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get device's own phone number, then it's not currently possible.

Comment: Am I the only one asking himself now: "How do apps like Whatsapp work on the WP devices, then?"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to get the own cell number in Windows Phone.